# Creating and downloading .xls file from JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, meteor, blob

I have the following code, which should encode JSON object to XLSX and then download it:

```
this.data = {
   foo: "xyz"
}
let json2xls = require('json2xls');
var data = json2xls(this.data);

let blob = new Blob([data], { type: "binary" });
let a = angular.element("a");
a.attr("href", this.$window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
a.attr("download", "myfile.xlsx");
a[0].click();
```

It indeed creates and downloads a file, but excel cannot open it.
I know for sure that below converting method works, because I can send `this.data` to the server, save it using `fs.writeFile()` and then download this file.

```
var data = json2xls(this.data);
```

How can I parse from JSON to XLS, and then save it as XLS in a browser?

Comment: Is there a particular error you get?  Maybe it's an issue with the mime type?  I would also suggest to open the .xlsx in a text editor and maybe even lint the XML there to see if it's valid.  Maybe there is something you have to do with the JSON format to make it work with `json2xls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done server side:

- Install exceljs

`meteor npm install -s exceljs`

- Then you can generate the file this way:

`import Excel from 'exceljs';`

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/your-download-url', function(req, res, next) {
  // Use params to specify parameters for the xls generation process...
  const params = req.url.split('/');
  // ... for example /your-download-url/your-user-id
  // params[0] will be 'your-download-url'
  const user = Meteor.users.findOne(params[1]);

  const workbook = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter({});
  workbook.created = new Date();
  workbook.modified = new Date();
  const sheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Your sheet name');

  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Disposition': `attachment;filename=${filename}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
  });
  workbook.stream.pipe(res);

  const headers: [
        { header: 'Column 1', key: 'col1', width: 20 },
        { header: 'Column 2', key: 'col2', width: 15 },
  ];
  sheet.columns = headers;

  // User sheet.addRow(rowData) to add each row in your sheet.

  workbook.commit();
});
```

Comment: I did like you presented and it works, but only if I put this url directly into the browser. When I try to download it using angular $http, the download succeeds, but the file is twice bigger and thus excel cannot open it: `this.$http({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "/foo",
                }).then((response) => {
                    var file = new File([response.data], "hello world.xlsx", { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" });
                    fileSaver.saveAs(file);
                })`